# Use a list of edges to draw a graph

Tags: java, graph

I need a way to split up a set of vertices into separate components using nothing but a list of edges.

For example, if the program is presented with the input

2,3

1,5

3,4

4,2

I need to have the 1 and 5 placed in a separate structure from the 2, 3, 4 since they're not connected.

Would it be a good idea to put all the vertices into an adjacency list and if so, what would determine how they're split?

Also keep in mind that the number of vertices and the number of edges are both known, but variable.

Comment: how is this different from a disconnected graph? I don't think you need any separate structure for this

Comment: If a structure is needed, then you might look for an adjacency matrix.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear; I have no problem getting the input and storing it in a list or matrix. I need to know how to use that, perhaps with a depth first search, to find out things such as whether one vertex is connected to another. So if i have 2,3 and 3,4 and 1,5 i need to know that 2 is connected to 3 AND 4 but not to 1 or 5. If anyone has an Idea how to put that in code that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood you correctly, then you really can use something like depth-first-search.
when you come to some point, you mark it with index 0 (for example).
when it seems that you walked through all points in connected structure (your search finished)
you start iterating over array of points to see if there is some point that is not marked (with 0), so start running depth-first-search on that point and mark all points with 1...
so then you'll be able to analyse array of points and see that some of them are marked with  0, some are 1, some has mark 2... so if you have 0,1,2 then you have 3 separate structures.

Hope it was useful.

Comment: ohhhh... That's actually pretty clever! And doing that would tell me which points are in which structure as well. Any chance you could show me how to run a DFS?

Comment: sorry for late response, so just for history here is the link that describes the concept:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/DepthFirstSearch.java.html